# Converting custom type in Java with bukkit

Tags: java, type-conversion, bukkit, custom-type

How to convert String to (custom Type) Enchantment? Following code alerts "*Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Enchantment*"

```
String s = "DAMAGE_ALL.2";
String[] enchantINFO = s.split(".");

Enchantment enchantTYPE = enchantINFO[0]; //TODO Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Enchantment
int enchantLVL = enchantINFO[1];

player.getItemInHand().addEnchantment( enchantTYPE , enchantLVL );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fit a `String` object into an `Enchantment` object.  Unfortunately, a `String` is not an `Enchantment`.

I'm not intimately familiar with the Bukkit API, however you will need to use one of the `Enchantment` constructors.  I would recommend you become more familiar with the Java programming language basics before writing your own mods and plugins, though, as a general rule.

Comment: And you are right, an answer is baset upon what you sugessted.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
Enchantment enchantTYPE = Enchantment.getByName(enchantINFO[0]);
```

Comment: Please accept your answer, so that people know your problem is solved and will not attempt to answer further.